# "Invalid Pointer" exception when calling WebClient.DownloadString in Azure PowerShell function

Tags: azure, powershell

I've got a daily Function I kick off on Azure.  Been working fine for months.  Suddenly it's failing every single day (for the last three) - but when I trigger it a second time it works fine.

The code that's failing is:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
[xml]$feed = $wc.DownloadString("https://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/u:andrewducker/")
```

The second line there gives the exception:

> Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call"

This strikes me as being due to some kind of internal change with Azure and PowerShell, but I'm not sure how to report that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure `WebClient` is still encouraged.
Maybe use `HttpClient` like this:
`$hc = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
[xml]$hc.SendAsync([System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new([System.Net.Http.HttpMethod]::Get, "https://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/u:andrewducker/")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`

Comment: Even easier `[xml]$feed = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/u:andrewducker/").Content`

Comment: As you have already open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/606118/34invalid-pointer34-exception-when-calling-webclie.html) & your issue was addressed posting  the Same to help the other community members. 

You can try using the HttpClient. The WebClient has been deprecated.

Comment: Hi.  I switched to Invoke-WebRequest, and am still getting exactly the same exception.
In both cases the actual exception is being thrown in System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync